# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8/3/2012"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

Why I'm getting these error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8/3/2012"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at com.exel.raf.seeit.ExecuteImport.excelDtToString(ExecuteImport.java:713)
    at com.exel.raf.seeit.ExecuteImport.generateItemHistorySql(ExecuteImport.java:649)
    at com.exel.raf.seeit.ExecuteImport.execute(ExecuteImport.java:56)
    at com.exel.raf.seeit.ExecuteImport.main(ExecuteImport.java:38)
    Process exited with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Post the code causing it.

Comment: 8/3/2012 is string value and you are parsing it as number , Double.parseDouble see 510 line of your code

Comment: What makes you think that "8/3/2012" is a valid number. There is some problem in your code. Please share the code fragment causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert String to Number. In the above case I think your String is "8/3/2012". For converting to any number, you must not have any characters other than numbers or you can have double if you want decimals.

This looks like a date, please explore the Date class and see how you can convert it to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Date 8/3/2012 is not proper numeric type. Check the line of code where you are parsing it to Double.

From the java docs,

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

[refer here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)